# Using Azure Application Insights REST API (https://dev.applicationinsights.io) to read custom events/metrics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Our service writes a lot of custom events and metrics to App Insights.
Using the AI portal we can make complex queries and see nice charts, but I would like to access the data from outside the portal.
The Azure Application Insights REST API page (https://dev.applicationinsights.io) claims that those API can be used to perform such task, but I am unable to make them work - again I want to query custom events and metrics, not the standard ones.
Does anyone have any examples?
Here is for example one our queries:

```
customEvents
| where name startswith "Monitor.Xxxxxxx"
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1min)
| order by timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using the wrong AppId/Key; once I plugged the correct ones I am able to use the API Explorer.